# Grouping snapshots copied by DLM in cross region

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-ebs

We use `AWS DLM` to create an automated snapshot for instances with specific tags and copy them to cross regions using the policies.
These DLM policies will be configured to invoke on every hour. Those instances have 2 EBS disks so individual snapshots are created for each EBS. we can group the snapshots for the particular instance using the tag we added ie) **instance-id**.But there are 24 individual snapshots(2 volumes x 12 hours) for each instance at the end of the 12 hours. In the source region, I can group the snapshot by creation time, but at the cross-region, we lack the information to group snapshots and are not able to create an AMI with valid snapshot combination in which the instance will be restored.

We have already evaluated `AWSBackup` service and we are aware of it, the task is to implement the logic with `AWS DLM`.
If anybody faced/solved the same issue, Kindly provide the steps or suggestions to overcome the issue.